# Pushing objects in a list Apex

Tags: apex, list

I have an list of object eg:

```
List a = 1 , 2, 3, 4
```

now i want to push an object in position 2 , i.e

```
a.push(5,2) // push 5 in position 2
// 1,2,5,3,4 is the value of a
```

how can i achive this in apex?

Comment: I've downvoted this one because there is no apparent research done.

Comment: The [List Class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm) is a good place to start.

Comment: yes, i see my fault i don't see further downvotes as necessary -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of thing that you should look at the official documentation for as part of your research.

From [the documentation on the List class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm), the `.add(index, listElement)` looks like it should be a natural fit.

And after a quick test, it does do exactly what you'd hope.

```java
List<Integer> alist = new List<Integer>{1, 2, 3, 4};
aList.add(2, 5);
system.debug(aList);
```